# Retrieving data from yahoo finance with VBA

Tags: excel, indexing, finance, yahoo-finance, yahoo-api

I wish to extract data from Yahoo Finance and populate it into an Excel spreadsheet. I'd like each stock to be represented by a single line, detailing the Ticker, Company Name, Stock Price, and similar information. However, I aim to gather data for every stock listed worldwide on Yahoo Finance. How can I achieve this, especially when I'm unaware of the stock tickers in advance?

I tried using the built-in data retrieval functions of Excel, and I also explored some third-party add-ins that promised to fetch stock data. I was expecting these tools to give me an option to download all stock data from Yahoo Finance at once, especially since I don't know all the tickers beforehand. However, I couldn't find a way to get the comprehensive data for every stock worldwide. I was hoping for a solution that would automate this process and populate my Excel sheet accordingly

Comment: This is not a free coding service. You need to show what you have done, why it does not work and any errors.

Comment: I was not asking for code but for the starting point. 
I see two issues: first yahoo will block my IP if I try to scrap 5000 stocks and second I don't know all the 5000 available stocks.